# How to redirect messages from one endpoint to another using java websockets (jsr 356)

Tags: endpoint, java-websocket, jsr356

I am doing a personal project to learn about java websockets. Basically my HTML clients sends messages to my server through [JSR 356 websockets](https://tyrus.java.net/index.html). The endpoint `@ServerEndpoint("/wsServer")` receives all messages from the clients and I would like to see those messages in another portal/endpoint `@ServerEndpoint("/wsDashboard")` as a dashboard in real time.

I would appreciate any idea, documentation or piece of code to start with as I really have no idea, I have seen solutions like apache kafka, but I am not sure if this is what I need.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create Java Web Socket Client for ***/wsDashboard***  on **onmessage** method of a @ServerEndpoint("/wsServer") end point and keep it in user properties. wher you receive a message just forward the message to /wsServer web socket.

```
   @ServerEndpoint("/wsServer")
    public class MyWSServerEndPoint{
 @OnOpen
public void open( Session session) {
    // Open java client websocket connection to /wsDashboard and keep the object in 
        session.getUserProperties().put("wsDashboard ", websocket);
     }
    @OnMessage
     public void onMessage(String  message,Session session){
  //forwarding the message
       session.getUserProperties().get("wsDashboard ").getRemote().send(message);
 }
    @OnClose
    public void onClose(Session session){
     session.getUserProperties().get("wsDashboard ").close();
     }

 }
```

To create a client end point here is good example 
http://www.hascode.com/2014/11/creating-different-websocket-chat-clients-in-java/